# Obtaining Dominant Frequency of a Time Series Data

Tags: python, fft

I am working on accelerometer data and am trying to find the dominant frequency of my data.
I use fft() function from fftpack in python. To find the dominant frequency I found the absolute value of the fft and found the frequency at which the magnitude is maximum. While doing this I get the dominant frequency to be around zero( 0-0.05 Hz). I've negated the DC content in the signal and found fft using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack

signal = signal - np.mean(signal)
freq = np.linspace(0.0, sampling_rate / 2.0, row // 2) # row:-no. of readings
signalFFT = fftpack.fft(signal)/row

plt.plot(freq, abs(signalFFT[:row//2]))
plt.show()
```

Even then I obtain the dominant freq to be around zero.

1. Is my method of finding the dominant freq and negating DC content correct?
2. What does a Zero Dominant Freq imply? Or in general what does a Dominant Freq = f Hz tell about the
   data?
3. What are the possible causes for Zero Dominant Frequency?
4. Is it possible for accelerometer reading to have a Zero Dominant Frequency when we know the data is
   being read from a moving object
5. What else can I do to get a Non-Zero Dominant Frequency?

Thanks a lot :)

Update 1:- Is there any rule that dominant frequencies of X, Y, Z axes of accelerometer should have a same or similar freq as Dominant Freq?
If **No** could anyone please explain with an example.

Comment: It could happen if your resolution is less. Resolution is samplaing_rate/N where is N is the number of frequencies you want your fft to be divided. If it is very high then all of your dominant freq will fall around zero.

Comment: when learning FFT is always super helpful to feed in known good data ... I suggest you find a WAV audio file containing a known constant frequency tone say 1 kHz and feed that into your FFT call and verify your code says its a 1 kHz signal  ...  this eliminates all of the unknowns except your FFT code

Comment: @ScottStensland, Thank for the feedback. As you've mentioned, I fed a WAV audio file of 1KHz to my code and I get a clear peak at 1000.0015Hz. So I think that means the code I have is correct isn't it?

Comment: Can you provide a plot of the signal with time in seconds on the x-axis? Since you mention XYZ components: are you sure that `signal` is a 1D array?

Comment: I'm using 3 axis data but while passing it through a fft its being passed 1 by 1. So essentially its a vector